# Adsense with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, adsense, ads

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161806/desperately-need-a-solution-for-adsense-that-works-with-ajax), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435391/refresh-a-div-that-has-a-google-ad-inside-it#441425) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394594/how-to-force-advert-to-show-on-ajax-loaded-page-adsense), but I think my situation is different.
I don't need to refresh Ads everytime I make an AJAX call.

I have a page call it "mypage.php". I load Adsense advertisement into first div, when page is opened. My second div is empty.

After DOM is fully loaded, i make an AJAX post. And put the result into "lower_content" div.
Does this break Adsense TOS?

```
<body>
  <div id="adSense_content>
    <script> adsense script </script>
  </div>

  <div id="lower_content">
    empty in start
  </div>
</body>
```

My js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/getit",
    success: function(data) {
            $("#lower_content").html(data);
        }
  });
}
```

Note: Why I don't load second content when page is opening? Because AJAX call replies in 6-7 seconds. When server load is high, response comes even in 10-15 seconds. To not to make visitor wait with empty page, or even bounce from the page. I show layout to visitor in start, and load content when the response of AJAX call came.

edit: Putting an ad to an empty page is againts Adsense TOS. But the page that I mentioned is empty while loading the table data. After loading the full table with AJAX the page is loaded with content. But ad is put while loading the html page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did some more research .. there is no easy solution to your problem.

If your site uses AJAX for a majority of the content then you can look at implementing the Google Ajax-Crawling (aka Hash-Bang) specs. This will ensure that that the Google bot and Adsense bot crawl your AJAX content. This will help with both relevant ads and search results. 
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

Or you have to wait till the Adsense for Ajax program start again. https://developers.google.com/adsense-for-ajax/

**Update:** Changed answer after more research.

Comment: Hmm interesting point.. But I make AJAX call after document.ready, because sometimes it becomes 10-15 seconds when the AJAX request is responded. (Because of server load etc.) So, to not to make visitor wait or even bounce from page, I show the sketch of the page to visitor, and fill the data parts after response of AJAX.

Comment: Changed answer after more research.

Comment: AdSense for AJAX has been discontinued.

Answer (score 7):

The default google adsense code is something like this:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- banner-name -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-12345678901234950"
     data-ad-slot="987654321"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Spit the code up into 3 parts to make it work on ajax loaded content.

Include the google script somewhere in your page (in your <head> for example) just once.

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Place the google code in your (ajax) content wherever you want the banner(s)

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-12345678901234950"
     data-ad-slot="987654321"></ins>
```

Trigger this function after your content has changed via ajax. (don't forget to trigger this on page load too, to display ads when pages isn't loaded via ajax.)

```
function displayGoogleAds(){
    $('ins').each(function(){
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    });
}
```

Ps. I'm not sure if google will allow this, since your modifying/changing up the code a little bit. But i'm currently using it this way.

Comment: Thank you so much... I´m using your current solution but sometimes it responses with "bad request" any idea?

Comment: @UrielUVD removing the 'async' part from the <script src> might help.

Comment: I don´t use the 'async', as I see, the request is blocked after a few of Ads are correctly displayed. According to a previous answer, this way is against the TOS of Google and currently AdSense for Ajax is discontinued... too bad.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly the page https://developers.google.com/adsense-for-ajax/ says Google no longer accepting new applications for AdSense for AJAX