# OK to clone Adsense ad for ajax lightbox?

Tags: jquery, ajax, clone, lightbox, adsense

I have a normal site with ads that offers lightbox links.

The lightboxes fill up with ajax content. Once done I want to display an ad. That's not possible (see [Adsense with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834751/adsense-with-ajax)).

Is it ok for Google if I clone the first ad block from the normal page into the lightbox (after the ajax content has loaded)?

I don't want to run into trouble tho.

Comment: While I can't speak to your specific use case, Google AdSense is very particular about how their ads are treated.  The last I read them, the terms of service did not permit you to modify their code in any way.  I'd imagine they wouldn't like your modal since it's basically another impression which wouldn't be tracked correctly on their end.  Could you try a creative solution where you modify the CSS of the ad container to place it on top of all elements, in the location you want?

Comment: Thanks, I had the same impression. Better no experiments. I can display a custom fallback ad tho :)

Comment: Adsense support now replied: Lightboxes fall uner the popup category which is forbidden. I think the real problem is that they can't control manipulation with AJAX as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6468298/370215