# Ajax website - Google DFP Small Business and Adsense

Tags: adsense, google-dfp

I am building an ajax based website . For Ajax based websites looks like DFP is a good solution for earning money . Also in DFP you can enable Adsense to show the ads ( you can refer below links) .

http://support.google.com/dfp_sb/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1670087

http://support.google.com/dfp_sb/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=112640

**1) DFP :-** You can use it in your ajax code

**2) Adsense :-** You can't show it using Ajax directly ( as per terms and conditions )

But can we show Adsense in DFP which I am loading using ajax ? Any one using this approach or does it violate terms and conditions of Ad sense ?

Thank You All

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about managing a business relationship, communicating between the question OP and a third party, and/or dealing with a legal issue. In other words, it's not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic]. You might be able to get help from the Customer Service for the company you are interfacing with. If you want an interpretation of legal requirements, it might be appropriate to ask on [law.se].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it. I asked this question in person at Google's "AdSense in Your City" event in the fall of 2012, and the reps said it was acceptable, and in fact advocated doing this.

Using DFP as a carrier for AdSense only is completely acceptable. You don't have to use DFP to manage other ads with only AdSense as a fall-back. You get the benefits and the drawbacks of DFP. You've mentioned one of the benefits. Another major one is built-in targeting... for example you could show larger, more obnoxious ads to users from countries with a lower eCPM to offset their lower ROI. One of the drawbacks is that the DFP stuff loads slower than AdSense, and its integration with AdSense reports and channels is quite poor. DFP AdSense units also seem to get new AdSense features later than "native" AdSense.

Comment: @user2989587 Yes, as of October 2014, everything I wrote about using DFP to deploy AdSense is still valid. However, "native" AdSense has in the mean time finally added quite a few features to handle responsive ads, and dynamic/AJAX websites, so you might not need DFP anymore. For instance, you can force AdSense to refresh ads when your page content refreshes -- useful for single-page JS-based web apps and stuff.

Comment: Any link to the new functionality? I cannot find anything, just old stuff. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @user2989587 Looks like this was my mistake regarding refresh -- it was a limited beta that was enabled on my account. I didn't realize it wasn't enabled for everyone. This does indicate that they are cooking up something for this usecase though, and I expect will have reason to as single page AngularJS webapps become more popular. Responsive ads are available for everyone, though -- it's an available unit size when you create a new ad. You can also add some code to give it a hint to make the responsive ad vertical, squarish, or horizontal.

Comment: Ok thankyou. About responsive I already knew, but about ajax loaded ads, there was years ago a beta program but they've cancelled it, and they dont have any plan on it in near time...At least is the information that I can find from this year.