# Refreshing ads on Google AdSense

Tags: javascript, ajax, refresh, adsense

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161806/desperately-need-a-solution-for-adsense-that-works-with-ajax), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435391/refresh-a-div-that-has-a-google-ad-inside-it) and in [this link](https://developers.google.com/adsense-for-ajax/) they say:

> We're no longer accepting new applications for AdSense for AJAX, but
>   we appreciate your interest in         the product and will continue
>   to work on new ways to monetize dynamic content.

But in [this link](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/3058726?hl=en) they have a sample explaining how to reload ads dynamically.

So, is Google Adsense accepting ads refresh?