# How can I prevent flicker of the whole page when the user click on Menu items in the master page

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, postback, menuitem, flicker

Is it possible to avoid the page flicker when the user clicks on the Menu items in the master page ? I tried different ways to avoid that e.g using `<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updateMenu"` in the master page included within the

```
            <div class="main">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
            </div>` but it doesn't work.
```

My code is something like that

```
         <asp:Menu  ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal"> 

            <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/home.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/welcome.aspx" Text="Welcome"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/item.aspx" Text="Item"/>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
```

Does attribute NavigateUrl work like Response.Redirect() method since Response.Redirect force refresh of the page.

If I would use site map will solve my problem ?

Please help me.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

NavigateUrl is nothing more than the href in a link. If you look at the rendered HTML, you'll probably see a 'a' tag with a href to home.aspx or welcome.aspx.

Loading a new (web) page will always result in some sort of flickering, since you're telling the browser to discard the page it has now and get and render a new one from the server. Whether you do this through a menu, through links or based on a sitemap, this won't change.

One thing you can do to minimize flicker is to create a default page which has all the default elements you need, and add a placeholder for page-specific content. Next, you can replace the content of the placeholder with the specific content for the page you're loading. This will reduce but not eliminate flicker, since there's still the need to get (part) of a web page from the server and replace the current HTML with the new HTML.

Another way would be to laod everything in your page and hide/show the item you need. This takes a whole different approach on navigation though, and will probably break the structure your website/web application has now.

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for your reply!! default elements that I need are the other pages included several panels and the third way is a bit naive approach...

Answer (score 0):

A `MenuItem` control renders a link to the page/resource which is set in your `NavigateUrl`. So every time you are clicking the link, you are loading a new page. So yes, it works similar to `Response.Redirect()`

If you want to avoid this "flicker" then you should look into loading up your page content via Ajax. I would avoid using the UpdatePanel as this always posts the whole page back to its self.

So I would suggest searching and looking into loading page content via Ajax, or take a look at this SO Question for a starter

[Is pjax the way to go for "fluid" navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148097/is-pjax-the-way-to-go-for-fluid-navigation)

Comment: thank you for your reply , about loading page content via Ajax should I use JQuery or Ajax controls ? could you give me some tips please?

Comment: Personally, I would learn to use jQuery and stick with that. Start off here http://api.jquery.com/load/ as this shows you how to load html pages into html elements